# Creating a scoring metric for IsolationForest GridSearchCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am doing an IsolationForest and I would like to optimised my hyperparameters using GridSearchCV. I would like my scoring to be based on the recall score of the outlier, i.e. label = -1. However, I am facing an error when running this code.

```
recall_fraud = make_scorer(recall_score(pos_label=-1))
gs_params ={
        'max_samples': [300,500,1000],
        'contamination': [float(y_train.count(-1))/len(y_train)] ,
        'max_features': [1,3,7],
        'n_estimators':[1000],
        'random_state':[1]
    }

isof_gs = GridSearchCV(IsolationForest(), gs_params, n_jobs = 1, verbose = 1, cv = 5, scoring = recall_fraud) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-d1f260f73f29> in <module>()
----> 1 recall_fraud = make_scorer(recall_score(pos_label=-1))
      2 gs_params ={
      3     'max_samples': [300,500,1000],
      4     'contamination': [float(y_train.count(-1))/len(y_train)] ,
      5     'max_features': [1,3,7],

TypeError: recall_score() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there something wrong that I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `make_scorer`, all the keyword arguments which you want to pass to the scoring function should be passed to the `make_scorer`, not the internal scoring function.

Look at the [`kwargs` param in `make_scorer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html):-

> **kwargs : additional arguments Additional parameters to be passed to score_func.

Change your code like this:

```
# Updated recall_score() to recall_score
recall_fraud = make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=-1)
```

and it will not throw error anymore.

The `pos_label` will be automatically forwarded to the recall_score method when actually calculating the recall of the grid-search.

Comment: hmm. the same error still comes up even when I follow your method. does it work for you?

Comment: @TimOng Aah yes, my bad. I need to remove the parentheses from the recall_score. Updated the answer to reflect the same.